# Agregar valor especifico sobre cada barra

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Estoy trabajando con Python3 y Matplotlib y deseo poner sobre cada barra su valor correspondiente en Y. ¿Es posible esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que no has tenido respuestas y yo tampoco lo sé, pero he encontrado algo que de momento te puede servir.
Por lo que veo, la función personalizada "autolabel" hace lo que estás buscando.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()


def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')


autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image: Resultado del ploteo]

Espero te sea útil!